# Nested While loops in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I want to change my SQL code which generates n table using two nested While loops, like:

```
DECLARE @count1 INT
SET @count1 = 2012
 DECLARE @count2 INT
 SET @count2 = 1
 WHILE @count1 <= 2016
 BEGIN
WHILE @count2 <= 12
  create table LGDfigRecov as
select   ...
from ...
WHERE FD0.mo_id=count2
   AND FD0.an_id= count1
...
SET @count2 += 1
END
SET @count1 += 1
END
```

How can I change every time the name of new table like "LGDfigRecov +count1+count2"? It means I want to create every time a new table with the name of year and month at the end.

Comment: Dynamic SQL - meaning you build a string of your sql command in sql and then execute the string.

Comment: How about *one* table with columns containing count1, count2

Comment: First of all SQL SERVER does not allow to create a table like this `create table LGDfigRecov as
select   ...` you need dynamic query

Comment: It really sounds like you need *one* table with a column that stores the year and month

Comment: @AlexK. that is now the situation

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen, thanks for your hint. Where can I find an example of Dynamic SQL? Since I have never heard about it and have no idea.

Comment: I think this would be a good entry point: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-dynamic-sql-part-1 .Especially the last example (it's an old article though so look up sql flavour changes to your specific version)

Comment: Those count variables, it's like you try to create tables for each month.  Wouldn't it be much easier to have one table with a [partitioning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188730(v=sql.110).aspx) on the year+month?

Comment: @LukStorms yes you may be right, but I wanted to have separate table. I found the idea with the dynamical sql nice. But thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a query like this to create your statements.

```
WITH 
MonthNumbers AS (SELECT * FROM(VALUES('01'),('02'),('03'),('04'),('05'),('06'),('07'),('08'),('09'),('10'),('11'),('12')) AS x(MonthNr))
,YearNumbers AS  (SELECT * FROM(VALUES('2012'),('2013'),('2014'),('2015'),('2016')) AS x(YearNr))
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY YearNr,MonthNr) AS SortInx
      ,CONCAT('CREATE TABLE LGDfigRecov_',YearNr,'_',MonthNr,' AS ', CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)) +
       CONCAT('SELECT ... FROM ... ', CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)) + 
       CONCAT('WHERE FD0.mo_id=',MonthNr,' AND FD0.an_id=',YearNr,';') AS Cmd
FROM MonthNumbers
CROSS JOIN YearNumbers
```

I always try to avoid unnecessary loops and procedural approaches...

- Check them if they are valid syntax (just copy the output in a new query window)
- Open a `CURSOR` from this `SELECT`
- Use the `CURSOR` to fetch this row-wise into a variable `@Cmd`
- Use `EXEC (@Cmd)`

Comment: I get unfortunately the following error: ERROR : Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.

Comment: Try to copy the whole result-set into a new query window and check for syntax errors. You must - of course - replace the `SELECT ... FROM ...` with proper approproiate column and table names... When implementing the `CURSOR` Id advise to add a `PRINT @Cmd` and out-comment the `EXEC(@Cmd)`. This way you can re-check the statements which are going to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Below code will help to achieve your goal.

`DECLARE @count1 INT,
        @w_SQL nvarchar(4000);
SET @count1 = 2012
 DECLARE @count2 INT
 SET @count2 = 1
 WHILE @count1 <= 2016
 BEGIN
WHILE @count2 <= 12
  SET @w_SQL = 'create table LGDfigRecov' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @count1) + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @count2) + 'as
select   ...
from ...
WHERE FD0.mo_id=count2
   AND FD0.an_id= count1
...'

EXEC sp_executesql @w_SQL 
SET @count2 += 1
END
SET @count1 += 1`

Comment: it dose not work, probably because I am using the sql within SAS. However, thanks!